# Apache Serving Default Self Signed Certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I added the following code to my apache config file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/decrypted-private-key.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/gd_bundle.crt

ErrorLog logs/ssl.domain.com.error_log
CustomLog logs/ssl.domain.com.access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache restarts just fine.

when i navigate to my site however, I get an 'untrusted connection' warning.  Digging in a little deeper, chrome shows me the certificate is named 'phoneme1' (no idea where this certificate resides) and that it is self-signed (my certs are signed by godaddy).  It makes me think something is being overridden by a setting elsewhere.  Any thoughts on how to get the right SSL certificate to serve?

This is on CentOs 6.2, running apache.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `/usr/sbin/httpd -S` ?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome normally adds "http://www." if you type "domain.com", so I assume the request goes to "www.domain.com" which is a different host than domain.com when you're using NameVirtualHost.

So I'd suggest trying to add the following line to your configuration:

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

Of couse you have to restart the apache2 or at least you must reload the configuration!

Edit (22:43 local time): This answer assumes that all certificate files are valid and accessible!

Comment: In my tests chrome is not automatically adding `www` to URLs you enter.

Comment: Do you just enter "domain.com" or "http://domain.com"?

Comment: Just "domain.com" but not literally "domain.com", since the owners of domain.com setup a 301 redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com. I have my own .com domain with which I tested it.

Comment: Thanks very much for posting.  This didn't quite do it for me.  The self-signed certificate is continuing to serve.